# In oracle SQL am trying to print dates in one column which is between two date column

Tags: oracle

Below is an example, I have a similar data and I am looking to concat dates between two date fields

Table **ABC**

| ID | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/03/2021 | 22/05/2021 |
| 1 | 05/06/2022 | 15/10/2022 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023 | 18/04/2023 |
| 3 | 29/03/2020 | 06/06/2020 |
| 3 | 31/05/2023 | 11/08/2023 |
| 3 | 12/12/2022 | 20/03/2023 |

Am looking to get dates between From and To column and print it in Results column with separated by ;
The output should look something similar like below.

| ID | From | To | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/03/2021 | 22/05/2021 | 01/04/2021; 01/09/2022 |
| 1 | 05/06/2022 | 15/10/2022 | 01/07/2022; 01/08/2022 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023 | 18/04/2023 | 01/02/2023; 01/03/2023 |
| 3 | 29/03/2020 | 06/06/2020 | 01/04/2020; 01/05/2020 |
| 3 | 31/05/2023 | 11/08/2023 | 01/06/2023; 01/07/2023 |
| 3 | 12/12/2022 | 20/03/2023 | 01/01/2022; 01/02/2023 |

Thanks in advance...

Comment: read up on listagg

Comment: This is an iterative process. The easiest approach will be to write a simple PL/SQL function for this. In SQL you would have to write a recursive query.

Comment: Each task consists of different steps and you should decide for each step if you are able to do this or not. There's no a single function for every specific task, so breaking this down results into: 1. How to generate dates between two dates? 2. How to convert date into string of desired format? 3. How to combine different string values into single value separated by something (or more focused: by `;`)? 4. How to apply this 3 steps to each row for large/small table? What step is your current issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recursion and functions add_months() and listagg():

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/raLwQhyv)

```
select id, dt1, dt2, 
       (select listagg(add_months(trunc(dt1, 'month'), level),';') 
               within group (order by level) from dual 
        connect by add_months(trunc(dt1, 'month'), level) < dt2 ) dates
from abc
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this does help. I got the required output

Comment: One more question, on the above question for each line we are concating the dated between two dates (from and to). Incase if I want to do the same and aswell grouping by ID, how would I do that. I tried to tweak the above script but was unsuccess.

Example, 

ID From         To                 Result
1 12/03/2021 22/05/2021 01/04/2021; 01/09/2022;01/07/2022; 01/08/2022; 01/10/2022

Comment: Please ask new question and show input data and output you need and explain how dates should be aggregated for each id. Now I don't know if these are overlapping periods or continuous. Please be precise and show your query even if it is not working. Ideally if you prepare data in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), this way you will get answers faster / better, because people see structure and values.